# Return array of indexes

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am passing a number to find all indexes in the array where this number located, but the following implementation returns only a single index not all of them.

I wonder what I am missing.

```
findNumberIndexes (givenNumber : number)
{
   var inds = array.findIndex(index=> index === givenNumber)
}
```

For example:

```
array = [1,5,7,2,3,4,3,2]
givenNumber : 2
expected output : [3,7]
```

Comment: Please read the 1st sentence of [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and pay attention to words in bold.

Answer (score -1):

`array.map((e, i) => {if(e === givenNumber) { return i }}).filter(x => x!==undefined);`

`e` is for element, and `i` is the index. So `map(e, i)` returns all the indices where element is equal to givenNumber.`filter(x=>x)` removes all the `undefined` values.

edit: from `filter(x=>x)` to `filter(x=>x!==undefined)`

Comment: This will filter out the first item if index 0 is a match

Comment: @user184994 You're right